# Show error message if string has no value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add some validation on my code to show if there is any data or not in the database:

This is my code

```
public PartsRequestL SavModal(int Pk, string partNum)
{
    M9Lib.Models.PartsRequest PR = new PartsRequest("new", string.Empty);
    double price = 0.00;
    string PartCode = PR.getAltPartCode(partNum, ref price);

    PartsRequestL partListModel = _partsRequestLRepository.Get(c => c.Pk == Pk);

    partListModel.PartNum = PartCode;

    Save();
    return partListModel;
}
```

getAltPartCode checks if the partNum is available in the database.

```
partListModel.PartNum = PartCode
```

"PartCode" is sometimes empty because it doesn't match the PartNum

I need a validation to show if partCode has any data then carry on as normal, if not show an error before submitting (save).

Comment: `String.IsNullOrEmpty(PartCode)` may do what you want, if I read your question right.

Comment: where can i put this inside the code, and am assuming there will be a if statement...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string PartCode = PR.getAltPartCode(partNum, ref price);

if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(PartCode))
{
  //do whatever needs to happen when no partcode is returned
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(PartCode != null)
{
       PartsRequestL partListModel = _partsRequestLRepository.Get(c => c.Pk == Pk);

        partListModel.PartNum = PartCode;

        Save();

}
```